# MPDF generates blank pages before content instead of breaking table to 2 pages

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I've got strange problem on pdf generation via `MPDF` (5.7 version).

HTML for pdf contains pretty much 1 div and table inside it:

```
<div style="width: 992px; height: 1403px; margin: 0 auto; padding-left: 30px; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;">

    <TABLE BORDER BORDERCOLOR=#fff CELLSPACING=0 WIDTH=100%>
```

Table content doesn't fit 1 page, so it should have break for 2 pages somewhere inside, but instead it adds 4 blank pages before content, then outputs 1 `tr` on page which is 1 line and on last page rest of the table.

Here's `MPDF` config:

```
    $mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4', '6', '', 10, 10, 7, 7, 10, 10);
    $mpdf->charset_in = 'utf-8';
    $mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit = 0;
    $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);
```

`shrink_tables_to_fit` cannot be removed, since it's document for print.

Other templates work fine with tables breaking into pages.

Is there any way to fix this?

**UPDATE:**
Issue gone after upgrading to 6.0 version.

Comment: Sometimes mpdf don't show css as you can view in browser. be careful with that height: 1403px in the main div. (But i don't know if this is exactly the problem)

Comment: This doesn't help also (with height)

Answer (score 0):

Check **mPDF** plugin and used only supported CSS and try with this **mPDF** code.

```
    $mpdf=new mPDF(); 
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; 
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

Comment: could you please give me a full html?

Comment: full html is 1000 lines of code, and it's no point to post here.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with Version:5.7.2, I have resolved this by removing **colspan** and **rowspan** from the table without upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use page-break options in additional `div` to get control of breaks.